# Kubernetes persistent volume not allowing read or write

Tags: kubernetes, file-permissions, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc

I'm following [this](https://faun.pub/jenkins-inside-kubernetes-bdee0340e0ca) tutorial to create a jenkins server on my Kubernetes server.

I've got a volume

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: jenkins-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1000Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/t1/kubernetes/vol/"
```

and a volume claim

```
---
# PersistentVolume for Jenkins
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: jenkins-pv-claim
  namespace: ns-jenkins    # PV are not scoped to any namespace, but pvc is associated with the namespace
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

If I navigate to the mounted location inside Jenkins and run `touch test`, I get `touch: cannot touch 'test': Permission denied`

User looks right.

```
$ id
uid=1000(jenkins) gid=1000(jenkins) groups=1000(jenkins)
```

I've even gone so far as to make the host folder 777 permissions and no luck.  What's going on?

Comment: can you add `kubectl describe sc manual` output

Comment: have you tried with `fsGroup` as `1000`?